# PHP: Getting URL Referral Key

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm working on an email referal link for user registration with PHP.

The idea is that when you register, a random string is generated as a url referral and sent to your inbox. Then when you click the link in the email you get sent to a page that confirms your account.

However I've been running into problems getting the referral key from the URL and matching it with the DB.

So far this is what I have:

```
// example URL - http://example.come?ref=5493tgfd83

$passkey = $_GET['ref'];
$success = true;


$checkKey = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE confirmCode ='$passkey'";
$confirmKey = mysql_query($checkKey);

if($confirmKey){
    $countKey = mysql_num_rows($confirmKey);
}

// key doesn't match redirect to 404
if($countKey != 1 ){
        header("Location: 404.php");
        $success = false;
}
```

At the moment, the query isn't running and the page isn't redirecting as I expect. i.e if I enter the wrong key, the page doesn't redirect.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: is this the exact code? because `$tbl_name` is undefined.

Comment: Its a part of on app, that we should think about for you?

Comment: It's defined earlier.

Comment: Set the following in your `php.ini` file and restart your web server - `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`. Chances are you're hitting some undefined indexes and / or variables.

Comment: did you try to step-by-step debug using `var_dump()` the following?. Example: before the line `if($countKey != 1){`, try to examine the earlier parts.

Comment: Why not just do `if($confirmKey == $passkey)`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- For starters, `$confirmKey` is a *mysql* result resource

Comment: I just noticed that now @Phil my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two working examples that will get you going.

You will get better results by using `num_rows`

**Using mysqli_* functions with prepared statements:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// $passkey = $_GET['ref'];
$passkey = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['ref']);

$tbl_name = "yourtable";

// $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE confirmCode=?";
$query = "SELECT confirmCode FROM $tbl_name WHERE confirmCode=?";

if ($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $passkey);

        if($stmt->execute()){

            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1){

            echo "Code verified.";
            exit;

            }

else{ 
echo "Sorry.";
// uncomment below and delete the above echo
//    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
//    header("Location: 404.php");
//    exit;
}
        }
    }
```

---

**Using mysql_* functions:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$connect = mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx") or die("Error Connecting To MYSQL Server");
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die("Error connecting to database");

// $passkey = $_GET['ref'];
$passkey = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ref']);

$tbl_name = "yourtable";

$checkKey = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE confirmCode ='$passkey'";
$confirmKey = mysql_query($checkKey);

if (mysql_num_rows($confirmKey)) {
echo "Code verified.";
}

else{
echo "Sorry.";
// uncomment below and delete the above echo
//    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
//    header("Location: 404.php");
//    exit;
}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score 0):

Add a exit when you redirect the page

```
if($countKey != 1 ){
        header("Location: 404.php");
        exit;
}
```

and furthermore, its better to add a HTTP status to tell the browser the behavior your code to be, and do more friendly for SEO

```
if($countKey != 1 ){
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        header("Location: 404.php");
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use the MySQL extension for [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Second, you aren't doing any error checking or making sure that values have been set.

Here's a nice little PDO example to get you on the right path...

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxxx;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
]);

$ref = isset($_GET['ref']) ? $_GET['ref'] : null;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(sprintf('SELECT 1 FROM `%s` WHERE confirmCode = ?', $tbl_name));
$stmt->execute([$ref]);
if (!$stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    http_response_code(404);
    header('Location: 404.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at using PDO

Comment: @user3143218 You can also use *mysqli* but unless you need to use some very MySQL specific native functions, I find the PDO API easier to work with. Also, it throws exceptions which are easier to manage than checking all of your `mysqli_*` function return values.